# Sort item before group by in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to show my items in pagination method.
the first part happened by grouping them by i don't know how can sort them too .
in code `Item.page` contain each item page number and `Item.priority` contain
order of item.
now how can i sort by order too ?

this is my code :

```
"@model IEnumerable<MyProgram.Models.Question>" 

foreach (var group in Model.GroupBy((item => item.Page)))
        {

        <fieldset>

         <legend></legend>
       @{
            foreach (var item in group)
            {

                if (item.Type == "label")
                {
```

i tired this but nothing came up after `item.` :

```
foreach (var group in Model.GroupBy((item => item.Page)).OrderBy(item => item.))
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve - are you trying to sort the items within the group, or sort the groups themselves (one group before another)? Also, is this LINQ to Objects or does your `Model` expose an `IQueryable<>`?

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry i didnt post my total code :
its MVC => "@model IEnumerable<MyProgram.Models.Question>"
Model gets value from Controller.
exactly im trying to sort items in groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shall work:

```
Model.GroupBy(item=>item.page)
    .Select(group=>group.OrderBy(I=>I.priority))
```

You need each group to be ordered not the entire grouped enumerable.

Answer (score 0):

try in second `foreach`

```
foreach (var item in group.OrderBy(i => i.priority))
```

if your only goal is to achieve sorting by two or more parameters use `OrderBy(...).ThenBy(...)`